# Offline APP: needs authorization to yearly refresh of the 'Apple Developer Program' subscription

Tags: ios, swift, macos, apple-developer

I have developed an app that I exported from Xcode, it works offline, I don't have access to internet connection.

- Does the app stop to work if it's offline?
- Does the app need internet to read the authorization of the 'Apple Developer Program' subscription?
- How often do the authorization renews?
- Does the app find the authorization automatically or does it need to be upgraded with the authorization?

Thanks

Does anyone already experienced this?

Comment: Is this app for distribution?

Comment: It doesn't matter if the app is online or offline. An ad hoc build will stop working when the developer certificate that signed it expires. This will be at most 12 months. You will then need to create a new ad hoc build with a new certificate and install that build

Comment: @Paulw11 an apple dev cert can be made to be valid for several years.  the ability to sign with an apple dev cert indeed depends on an annual 12-month subscription.  apple dev intermediate cert expires in 2030.  ad hoc does not require apple dev, so you may request your own signature from your own certificate authority arbitrarily.

Comment: @RichardBarber The OP has tagged both macOS and iOS, so there are different considerations.  macOS is fine; You can run forever.  For iOS an ad-hoc app will only run until the provisioning profile expires, which is the renewal date of the developer program membership.  After that a new build will be required.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a personal Mac application it just keeps working forever. But if it's an iOS app it will stop working on your device eventually.

Also "offline" is a red herring. Apps don't "phone home".

Comment: Apps phone home to check the notary ticket against the mothership.

Comment: @RichardBarber Not if they're not notarized, they don't. Believe me, I have personal Mac apps that I've been using (and distributing independently of Apple) for years.

Comment: If there is no ticket attached to the app it phones home to see if one exists.

Comment: @RichardBarber It doesn't. I have lots of personal Mac apps and they don't. They wouldn't even know where "home" is. Trust me on this one.

Comment: Sorry Matt, phoning home is a thing, this has been established: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/391379/does-macos-phone-home-to-apples-servers-before-running-an-app-for-the-first-tim

Comment: @RichardBarber That's gatekeeper. An app that you simply create on your own computer for your own personal use, or that you install at the lowest (hidden) gatekeeper level, is under the gatekeeper radar.

Comment: Right! Gatekeeper is the phone for apps signed by an apple dev cert.  It appears as though the author was discussing apple dev as a next step from ad hoc.  That means notary and on recent macos versions, phoning home.

Comment: I really think you're confusing ios with Mac. You don't need ad hoc or anything else to run a personal Mac app. Nor do you need to notarize to distribute.

Comment: ...in the old days.